# In ElasticSearch is there is limit to the number of items in a terms query?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the ES docs it lists this sample query:

```
{
  "terms": {
    "tags": [
      "blue",
      "pill"
    ],
    "minimum_should_match": 1
  }
}
```

Is there a limit (or a practical limit) on the number of items I could put in the list of possible strings to search for?  Could I have a hundred items here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaa, you can put thousands of item there(i've tested).. just follow the syntax. Then you are ok.